# Using Rxjs to invoke simultaneous chunks of requests in parallel with delay?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a queue of tasks (20 in length) where each tasks is an ajax request to be invoked .

I want to :

1) Create chunks of 5       ( 20/5 =4 chunks)
2) Execute each chunk where each *item in chunk* will be executed with delay of 1000 ms.
3) When each chunks item complete , wait 3 seconds .

So :

1..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..2..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..3..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..4..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..5.....................<sub>3sec</sub>..........
6..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..7..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..8..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..9..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..10..................... <sub>3sec</sub>..........
...
11..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..12..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..13..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..14..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..15..................... <sub>3sec</sub>..........
16..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..17..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..18..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..19..<sub>1sec( ↦ green)</sub>..20

I did manage to do something close :

[image]

With :

```
from(this.httpCodes)
      .pipe(bufferCount(5),
       concatMap((i, y) => from(i).pipe(mergeMap(f => {
                                    this.httpCodes[f.index].wasExecuted = true;
                                     return this.ajaxAlike(f.data).pipe(
                                                               catchError(() => { return of(-1) }),
                                                               map((r) => ({ res: r, data: f }))
                                                                      )
                                                      }) 
                                        ,delay(3000) )),

      )
```

But   it doesn't executed as I intended. I don't see delays between each item in chunk

**Question:**

Why do I see so many requests , And how can I change my code so that each item in a chunk will be executed with a 1 sec delay (green should be appear after each second) , and - after each chunk , wait 3 seconds?

[**Online Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajax-chunks-alike-rxjs-with-dalay-jmx6py?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **delay** operator delays an emitted item. It seems like you expect it to emit the item and then 'sleep' for 3 seconds before emitting the next. To achieve this you can **concat an empty delayed observable**.

You can create the following *pipeable* **sleep** operator:

```
const sleep = ms => concat(Rx.Observable.empty().pipe(delay(ms)))
```

And use it as follows:

```js
const {concatMap, concat, delay, bufferCount} = Rx.operators;

const sleep = ms => concat(Rx.Observable.empty().pipe(delay(ms)));

const ajaxAlike = call => Rx.Observable.of(call).pipe(delay(500));

Rx.Observable.range(0, 20).pipe(
  bufferCount(5),
  concatMap(calls => 
    Rx.Observable.from(calls).pipe(
      concatMap(call => ajaxAlike(call).pipe(sleep(1000))),
      sleep(3000)
    )
  )
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the 1 sec delay between each item ? The ajax delay is just a simulation for ajax.....i want to emit ajax request- and wait a 1 sec before next one

Comment: In other words , imagine there is no delay in the ajaxAlike method  , I still want to wait 1 sec after the ajax emission. In other words,  to see green and then wait 1sec. Not emit , wait 1 sec and then green

Comment: The "1..1sec( ↦ green)" got me thinking you want the 1 sec delay before the green. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Ok, I guess now I see what you mean. I updated the fiddle, so that all chunk-parts get executed in parallel, but the chunks wait on each other to complete. So this should do the trick:

```
const chunkSize = 5;
const requestsWithDelay = httpRequests.map(obs => obs.delay(1000));

let chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < requestsWithDelay.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.push(requestsWithDelay.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
}

const chunkedRequests = chunks.map(chunk => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(...chunk).delay(3000));
const parallelChunkRequest = Rx.Observable.concat(...chunkedRequests);
parallelChunkRequest.subscribe();
```

**Original Answer:**

Something like this would give you the desired delays (given httpRequests as an array of observables):

```
const requestsWithDelay = httpRequests.map((obs, idx) => { 
  let msDelay = 1000;
  if ((idx + 1) % 5 === 0 && idx < httpRequests.length - 1) {
    msDelay = 3000;
  }

  return obs.delay(msDelay);
});

const request = Rx.Observable.concat(...requestsWithDelay);
```

This should work, but there would not be "actual" chunks of observables. The requests in each chunk would not be executed in parallel (like with using mergeMap), but successively.

To get the abservable of httpRequests you could something like this (but without the delay in the pipe):

```
const httpRequests = this.httpCodes.map(data => this.ajaxAlike(data));
```

But if you want the chunks to execute in parallel you could do something like this:

```
let chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < requestsWithDelay.length; i += 5) {
    chunks.push(requestsWithDelay.slice(i, i + 5));
}

const chunkedRequests = chunks.map(chunk => Rx.Observable.concat(...chunk));
const parallelChunkRequest = Rx.Observable.merge(...chunkedRequests);
```

I created a [demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yearn/6x1ffq8b/)

But why do you need the 3 seconds delay after each chunk, if they get executed in parallel and don't wait for each other?

Comment: Because i dont want the server to think im flooding it

Comment: I didn't really get the question right in the beginning and thought the chunks should run in parallel - but not the content of each chunk